# Geth-ing started

Tags: go-ethereum

I just installed geth in my windows 10 pc.
So far it seems ok (I think)
And I am really not an IT to understand some words in the console.
But...
what does this mean?:

```
INFO [06-25|13:32:07] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=36.094ms  processed=482211 pending=132637
```